# templateProvider fails silently when injecting $timeout

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Look at this simple repo that shows the issue:
https://github.com/juanmarinbear/app

When using this templateProvider function:

```
function template() {
  return '<div data-ng-include=\"\'/app/home/home.html\'\"</div>';
}
```

The template loads without issues.

When using this templateProvider function:

```
function templateBreaks($timeout) {
  return $timeout(function() {
    return '<div data-ng-include=\"\'/app/home/home.html\'\"</div>';
  });
}
```

The template fails to load and the controller doesn't instantiate.  No error is shown.

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to set a time for the timeout? `$timeout(function(){ return template }, 500);`

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Add a time, or just inject $timeout, it still fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try injecting the `$timeout` dependency properly by adding:

```
templateBreaks.$inject = ['$timeout'];
```

That should do the trick.

Your code seems to work fine with AngularJS 1.2 or lower (hence why it works on Plnkr) but the explicit dependency injection seems to be required as of AngularJS 1.3.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do you know why it isn't necessary to do so in the Plunker?

Comment: Is your code being minified?  That is the most likely source of it not working.  There's 3 ways to declare your dependencies: functionName.$inject = ['dependency']; -or- declaring it with a minsafe array on the module declaration, or using ngAnnotate (which does the same thing as step 1 but via a build script using grunt or gulp).  Angular will work just great without this minsafe array until you minify.

Comment: 1.3 just allows you to add "strict-di" to your app so that it will *crash* if you don't explicitly define it, but it shouldn't prevent you from doing so. There are grunt & gulp plugins that can add these dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it's a synchronous issue because the $timeout service returns a promise whereas the non-timeout version returns a string.

You could "wait" and then return the string.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?  How would you fix it in my repo?  I need to return the template after a brief period of time (a digest cycle).  Also, the problem is present even if I don't use $timeout but only inject it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the same end solution as above, but if you look at the [Sample App](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/app.js#L81) it also shows you could use an alternate syntax like so:

```
templateProvider: ['$timeout', templateBreaks],
```